# How to setup webhdfs hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I am trying to configure Hadoop with WebHDFS enabled, and then I also want to enable SSL on it. My hdfs-site.xml looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/hadoopusermnt/dfsdata/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/hadoopusermnt/dfsdata/datanode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

However I cannot make curl calls:

```
curl -ki "http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/tmo?op=GETFILESTATUS"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 50070 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

What am I missing? I am using Hadoop 3.3.4.

Comment: Are you sure 50070 is the correct port? Are you sure WebHDFS server is actually running?

Comment: No, not really clear, I check the Hadoop logs, but I don't see anything obvious which confirms either. How can I check this? 50070 is the default port, and I have not defined a port, so I assume its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the default port was changed to `9870`. It works with this port.